# Boot Error: Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot

Whenever I power on my computer I immediately get an endless stream of repeating errors on a black screen. The errors include the following:

Error: syntax error.
Error: incorrect command.
Error: can't find command: '???aN??'.

No keyboard commands appear to have any effect, nor does restarting.

Comment: What did you do to get to this state?

Comment: Please give detail of actions you did before this problem occurred.

Comment: Does this occur before, or after, logging in? Can you make a movie using your telephone, and load it to imgur.com. The most important piece to capture is the first error text that you see. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Status please...